# Hyper-V & Windows Server 2022 is creating a new network on each boot

Tags: windows, hyper-v, windows-server-2022

I have two virtual machines on my host (Windows Server 2022 and Windows 10) each time I reboot WS2022 it auto detects a new network on start however Windows 10 doesn't. So far we're up to network 20, but this is somewhat frustrating as I'd like it to stay on the original network on start. This is done through the prompt for turning on "network discovery" upon login.

Doesn't appear that anything changes in my local setup. Both VM's are connected to the "Default Switch". MAC addressing is set to "static" for this virtual machine and "MAC address spoofing" is disabled but I cannot see why it would detect a new network each time.

There seems to be limited documentation as to this behaviour but it would be helpful if it can be easily solved. Both Windows10 and Windows Server 2022 have the same settings in Hyper-V.

Just to clarify the below. OS version is Windows Server 2022 Standard, Version 21H2, OS Build 20348.350. Yes it does exist.